# How set image to center (vertical and horizontal) Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi i wont set image strongly to center of div via Bootstrap's classes. Without additional css.

Class (center-block) set image only on horizontally

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img class="center-block" src="/image.jpg"/>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        sometext
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And? What did you try to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Bootstrap has a class to do this kind of thing (at least not without additional CSS).

Perhaps try to set the div to `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` could work.